# Language level stuck at 7 when running JxBrowser example code?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, javafx, jxbrowser

I'm essentially just trying to get one of the JxBrowser example projects working by combining it with a basic JavaFX/Maven project.  When I run

`mvn clean javafx:run`

with the JxBrowser example code enabled (and the stock JavaFX code commented out), I get the following message:

`[28,32] static interface method invocations are not supported in -source 7 (use -source 8 or higher to enable static interface method invocations)`

[Java/FX Maven example project](https://github.com/openjfx/samples/tree/master/HelloFX/Maven/hellofx)

[JxBrowser example](https://github.com/TeamDev-IP/JxBrowser-QuickStart/tree/v7.32/Maven/JavaFX) (this curiously does not have JavaFX included in the pom.xml file)

[My GitHub repo](https://github.com/AlexMPalmisano/JxBrowser-Test/)

[My Java HelloWorld file](https://github.com/AlexMPalmisano/JxBrowser-Test/blob/main/src/main/java/HelloFX.java) (JxBrowser example code is commented out in this version)

Based on my searches on this issue, I've tried changing the language level in my Intellij Project Structure, but this seems to have no effect on the outcome.  I'm running OpenJDK version 17.0.6, so I'm not entirely sure why this would be an issue.  Is there anything I'm missing (I'm not very experienced so take it easy on me lol)?

EDIT: Here is the pom.xml file I'm currently running:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
  <artifactId>hellofx</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>demo</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <javafx.version>19</javafx.version>
    <javafx.maven.plugin.version>0.0.8</javafx.maven.plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>com.teamdev</id>
      <url>https://europe-maven.pkg.dev/jxbrowser/releases</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
      <version>${javafx.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.teamdev.jxbrowser</groupId>
      <artifactId>jxbrowser-cross-platform</artifactId>
      <version>7.32</version>
      <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.teamdev.jxbrowser</groupId>
      <artifactId>jxbrowser-javafx</artifactId>
      <version>7.32</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx.maven.plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>HelloFX</mainClass>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  
</project>
```

And here is the Java file:

```
import static com.teamdev.jxbrowser.engine.RenderingMode.HARDWARE_ACCELERATED;

import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.browser.Browser;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.engine.Engine;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.view.javafx.BrowserView;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HelloFX extends Application {

//    @Override
//    public void start(Stage stage) {
//        String javaVersion = System.getProperty("java.version");
//        String javafxVersion = System.getProperty("javafx.version");
//        Label l = new Label("Hello, JavaFX " + javafxVersion + ", running on Java " + javaVersion + ".");
//        Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(l), 640, 480);
//        stage.setScene(scene);
//        stage.show();
//    }

     @Override
     public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
         // Initialize Chromium.
         Engine engine = Engine.newInstance(HARDWARE_ACCELERATED);

         Browser browser = engine.newBrowser();

         // Load the required web page.
         browser.navigation().loadUrl("https://html5test.com");

         // Create and embed JavaFX BrowserView component to display web content.
         BrowserView view = BrowserView.newInstance(browser);

         Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(view), 1280, 800);
         primaryStage.setTitle("JxBrowser JavaFX");
         primaryStage.setScene(scene);
         primaryStage.show();

         // Shutdown Chromium and release allocated resources.
         primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> engine.close());
     }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }




}
```

EDIT 2: Here is the full readout on the new error I'm seeing.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------< org.openjfx:hellofx >-------------------------
[INFO] Building demo 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- clean:3.2.0:clean (default-clean) @ hellofx ---
[INFO] Deleting /home/palmisano64/Documents/SIT/EE552/Test/alex-Maven/hellofx/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> javafx:0.0.8:run (default-cli) > process-classes @ hellofx >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- resources:3.3.0:resources (default-resources) @ hellofx ---
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/palmisano64/Documents/SIT/EE552/Test/alex-Maven/hellofx/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- compiler:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) @ hellofx ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /home/palmisano64/Documents/SIT/EE552/Test/alex-Maven/hellofx/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< javafx:0.0.8:run (default-cli) < process-classes @ hellofx <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- javafx:0.0.8:run (default-cli) @ hellofx ---
[WARNING] There are 1 pathException(s). The related dependencies will be ignored.
[WARNING] Dependency: /home/palmisano64/.m2/repository/com/teamdev/jxbrowser/jxbrowser-cross-platform/7.32/jxbrowser-cross-platform-7.32.pom
   - exception: Only outputDirectories and jars are accepted on the path
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1082)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:893)
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: com.teamdev.jxbrowser.engine.NoLicenseException
        at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.engine.internal.LicenseExceptionFactory.create(LicenseExceptionFactory.java:65)
        at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.engine.internal.EngineImpl.newInstance(EngineImpl.java:280)
        at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.engine.Engine.newInstance(Engine.java:163)
        at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.engine.Engine.newInstance(Engine.java:117)
        at HelloFX.start(HelloFX.java:28)
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:839)
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:483)
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:456)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:455)
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$runLoop$11(GtkApplication.java:316)
        ... 1 more
Exception running application HelloFX
[ERROR] Command execution failed.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXBaseMojo.executeCommandLine (JavaFXBaseMojo.java:567)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXBaseMojo.executeCommandLine (JavaFXBaseMojo.java:434)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXRunMojo.execute (JavaFXRunMojo.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:342)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:330)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:160)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:827)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:272)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:195)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)
        at org.openjfx.JavaFXBaseMojo.executeCommandLine(JavaFXBaseMojo.java:567)
        at org.openjfx.JavaFXBaseMojo.executeCommandLine(JavaFXBaseMojo.java:434)
        at org.openjfx.JavaFXRunMojo.execute(JavaFXRunMojo.java:105)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2(MojoExecutor.java:342)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute(MojoExecutor.java:330)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:175)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000(MojoExecutor.java:76)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run(MojoExecutor.java:163)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute(DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:160)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:118)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:261)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:173)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:101)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:827)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:272)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:195)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  22.015 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-05-08T15:52:12-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.openjfx:javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.8:run (default-cli) on project hellofx: Error: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

EDIT 3: `mvn -v` output:

```
Apache Maven 3.9.1 (2e178502fcdbffc201671fb2537d0cb4b4cc58f8)
Maven home: /opt/apache-maven-3.9.1
Java version: 17.0.6, vendor: Eclipse Adoptium, runtime: /home/palmisano64/.sdkman/candidates/java/17.0.6-tem
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "6.1.21-v8+", arch: "aarch64", family: "unix"
```

Comment: Please include [mcve] code in the question as text, formatted as code.  Also include links to your research, referencing what you already tried.

Comment: Do you need to add the `maven.compiler.xxx` options to your `POM`?  `<modelVersion>x.x.x</modelVersion>
    <groupId>xxx.yyyy</groupId>
    <artifactId>xxxxxxxxxxxx</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>`

Comment: @SedJ601 I experimented that, and it seems to cause issues with one of the plugins in the JavaFX example pom.xml file.  Instead I get '[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.openjfx:javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.8:run (default-cli) on project hellofx'.  That specific part is included in the example w/o JxBrowser, so idk why it stopped working.

Comment: Can you please add the output of the command `mvn -v` and check that you are running maven with a suitable Java version?

Comment: @cyberbrain just edited the post with the output

Comment: Did you set IntelliJ > Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Java Compiler > Module & Target bytecode version?

Comment: I thought it was determined by the author of `JxBrowser` that your License was no longer valid and is at the root of this issue.

Comment: Also, your `POM` has `<maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>` which is a problem.

Comment: I have nothing to add to the previous comments, but I can explain why there are no dependencies on JavaFX. That's because JavaFX was a part of Java 8 and we keep our examples Java 8 compatible—on purpose. We do have an example for Java 9+ for Gradle though: https://github.com/TeamDev-IP/JxBrowser-QuickStart/tree/v7.32/Gradle/JavaFX-11

Comment: @VladyslavLubenskyi Let me clarify that Oracle bundled JavaFX with their own JDK/JRE products for Java 8. Then later Oracle stopped that bundling. **JavaFX has never been included in the definition of *Java Standard Edition*** despite being the official replacement for Swing. Today, some JDK vendors do provide an edition of their products that bundles the JavaFX/OpenJFX libraries. These vendors include Azul Systems (*ZuluFX*) and BellSoft (*LibericaFX*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Caveat:** I am *not* an expert on [*JxBrowser*](https://teamdev.com/jxbrowser/). I had not heard of it before today.

## No license

Excerpt from your error message:

> Caused by: com.teamdev.jxbrowser.engine.NoLicenseException

[JxBrowser](https://teamdev.com/jxbrowser/) is commercial software, requiring a fee. The [vendor does provide](https://teamdev.com/jxbrowser/#evaluate) a free 30-day trial.

Apparently you either do not have a license, or you have misconfigured the license files needed to execute JxBrowser.

Your code for establishing the JxBrowser engine seems to be too brief. The example code from xxx shows the following. Notice the call to `licenseKey` where you pass your license key as a string.

```java
EngineOptions options =
        EngineOptions
                .newBuilder( HARDWARE_ACCELERATED )
                .licenseKey( "your_license_code_goes_here" )
                .build();
Engine engine = Engine.newInstance( options );
```

There may be other ways to configure the license, but that one worked for me with my 30-day free trial license I obtained today.

## Java version

Your question does not document what settings you used to establish your Java version.

In IntelliJ, changing the Java version is quite a chore. You must reach into multiple nooks and crannies of IntelliJ settings as well as your Maven or Gradle configuration. Search Stack Overflow to learn more, as this has been covered already. I'll list some of the places briefly.

- IntelliJ > Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Java Compiler > Module & Target bytecode version
- IntelliJ > File > Project structure > Project Settings > Project > SDK  (and Language Level)
- IntelliJ > File > Project structure > Project Settings > Modules > Sources > language level
- Maven POM, with a plugin as shown next, with a `release` element.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.11.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <release>20</release>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

## Example app

If it helps, I can post the parts of an example app I got running today. I noticed too late that the TeamDev company provides a template on GitHub. So instead, I:

1. Created a new JavaFX project in IntelliJ using the built-in *JavaFX* project template.
2. Ran that project successfully.
3. Ripped out the FXML parts, though I imagine you could leave those in place and ignore them.
4. Tweaked the POM file to add JxBrowser elements, and update to latest version of everything.
5. Copied code from this [JxBrowser Quick Start](https://jxbrowser-support.teamdev.com/docs/quickstart/#quick-start-maven-view-javafx) page.
6. Copy-pasted four `--add-opens` items from the second block shown in the [*Embedding into JFXPanel*](https://jxbrowser-support.teamdev.com/docs/guides/troubleshooting/issues.html#embedding-into-jfxpanel) section of the JxBrowser page, *Frequently Encountered Issues*. I pasted into [*Run/Debug Configurations*](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration.html#create-permanent) dialog in IntelliJ, where I had to use the pop-up menu *Modify options* to check the *Add VM options* item which makes visible a field for pasting.
7. Used IntelliJ fix-it suggestions to modify my `module-info.java` file, as shown below.

```bash
--add-opens javafx.swing/javafx.embed.swing=jxbrowser
--add-opens javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.stage=jxbrowser
--add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.stage=jxbrowser
--add-exports javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control=jxbrowser
```

My module-info.java file:

```java
module work.basil.example.brzr {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires jxbrowser;
    requires jxbrowser.javafx;

    exports work.basil.example.brzr;
}
```

My POM.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns = "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation = "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>work.basil.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Brzr</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Brzr</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>com.teamdev</id>
            <url>https://europe-maven.pkg.dev/jxbrowser/releases</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>20.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.teamdev.jxbrowser</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxbrowser-cross-platform</artifactId>
            <version>7.32</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.teamdev.jxbrowser</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxbrowser-javafx</artifactId>
            <version>7.32</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>20</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>work.basil.example.brzr/work.basil.example.brzr.HelloApplication</mainClass>
                            <launcher>app</launcher>
                            <jlinkZipName>app</jlinkZipName>
                            <jlinkImageName>app</jlinkImageName>
                            <noManPages>true</noManPages>
                            <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                            <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

My `HelloApplication.java` file.

```java
package work.basil.example.brzr;

import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.browser.Browser;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.engine.Engine;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.engine.EngineOptions;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.view.javafx.BrowserView;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.Instant;

import static com.teamdev.jxbrowser.engine.RenderingMode.HARDWARE_ACCELERATED;

public class HelloApplication extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start ( Stage stage ) throws IOException
    {
        this.dumpEnv();

        // Initialize Chromium.
        EngineOptions options =
                EngineOptions
                        .newBuilder( HARDWARE_ACCELERATED )
                        .licenseKey( "your_license_code_goes_here" )
                        .build();
        Engine engine = Engine.newInstance( options );

        // Create a Browser instance.
        Browser browser = engine.newBrowser();

        // Load the required web page.
        browser.navigation().loadUrl( "https://html5test.com" );

        // Create and embed JavaFX BrowserView component to display web content.
        BrowserView view = BrowserView.newInstance( browser );

        Scene scene = new Scene( new BorderPane( view ) , 1280 , 800 );
        stage.setTitle( "JxBrowser JavaFX" );
        stage.setScene( scene );
        stage.show();

        // Shutdown Chromium and release allocated resources.
        stage.setOnCloseRequest( event -> engine.close() );
    }

    private void dumpEnv ( )
    {
        System.out.println( "Runtime.version() = " + Runtime.version() );
    }

    private Parent makeParent ( )
    {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText( "Say 'Hello World'" );
        btn.setOnAction( ( ActionEvent event ) -> System.out.println( "Hello World! " + Instant.now() ) );

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add( btn );
        return root;
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        launch();
    }
}
```

This example app ran successfully from within IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.2 Preview (Ultimate Edition), on an M1 MacBook Pro with macOS Ventura 13.3.1, using a JDK for Java 20.0.1 from Azul Systems.

When running, I saw a window appear within my app that looked like this:

[image: screenshot of running app]

---

By the way, I had a bit of trouble finding the JxBrowser Javadoc. Finally found it [here](https://api.jxbrowser.com/7.32/index.html).

Comment: Hi there from JxBrowser team. There are no Javadoc in our Maven repository, unfortunately. This is a limitation of the service provider and we plan to fix it in the future.

Comment: I'm a JxBrowser expert and I confirm correctness of this answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was able to get it to run finally, you're a life saver!  I followed some of the earlier suggestions and was able to make a bit  of progress, but it seems I was lacking the Run/Debug configurations, and I put the wrong information in the module-info.java file.  I greatly appreciate you taking the time to work this out and explaining it as thoroughly as you have.

Comment: @VladyslavLubenskyi thank you for your help, I appreciate your response to my help request on Twitter.